# Second identical Button doen not work

Tags: html

I would like an second add to cart button to my website page. I therefore copy & pasted the following button code a second time on my website page (at a diffferent place on the page). However, the second button does not work (i.e. when clicking it nothing happens, but is should lead you to the cart page)

```
          <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn" 
style="background-color:#FFA500">
              <span> {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}</span>
            </button>
```

Could someone take a look at the above code to see if there would be an error? or would someone have a clue why the second button on the same page does not work?

Many thanks.

Comment: IDs must be unique. Duplicate IDs may cause unexpected behavior. Try using a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) instead.

Comment: Did you make sure the new button has a different ID?

Comment: No I didn't so there may lie the problem indeed.

Comment: Sorry for the basic question but I am new to this, where in the code would I be able to find the ID matching the button?

Comment: Hard to say. My guess would be either in an external JavaScript file (for example, "example.js") or between `<script></script>` tags. Can you provide a link to the page?